# linq to xml: how to select the value from elements

Tags: xml, linq

I need return a list of the element `<AssetText>`. My query below only returns back the first `AssetText`. Any thoughts much appreciated.

```
var q = from c in xDoc.Descendants("Product")
        where (int) c.Element("ProductView").Element("ViewId") == 44
        select (string) c.Element("ProductView").Element("AssetText").Element("Text");
```

```
<Product>
  <ProductView>
    <ViewId>44</ViewId>
    <AssetText>
      <Text>my first Asset Text</Text>
    </AssetText>
    <AssetText>
      <Text>my second Asset Text</Text>
    </AssetText>
  </ProductView>
  <ProductView>
    <ViewId>45</ViewId>
    <AssetText>
      <Text>my third Asset Text</Text>
    </AssetText>
  </ProductView>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `Element("AssetText")` to `Elements("AssetText")` to get all the AssetText elements. Note that you'll need to change the rest of your query as well, otherwise it'll only match when the first ProductView has a ViewId of 44. I suggest you use a second "from" clause:

```
var q = from c in xDoc.Descendants("Product")
        from view in c.Elements("ProductView")
        where (int) view.Element("ViewId") == 44
        from assetText in view.Elements("AssetText")
        select assetText.Element("Text");
```